# App is running after closing

Tags: java, android

Anytime I try to close my foreground service, my app continues running even when none of my activities are opened. I've made a few allocation and function tracing tests and noticed that, however, my app is still open and uses a few MB of memory none of my methods are being called after closing the service. Only Java and Android stuff. Oh, and it looks like that my app also leaks memory during this. According to my app's Java heap, there are thousands of FinalizerReferences instantiated. Can this cause such a big problem or why can this occur?

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its Default android property, the app continiues to run in background even after you have closed ur app, few features like services etc run in background. Either you forcefully exis the app which i wouldnt suggest, or let android automatically close it when it requires

Comment: I don't think this is what supposed to happen. If I don't start the service and close my activity then it stops properly, but I doubt it's normal that my app uses resources after closing activity and foreground service. It uses about 10 MB of RAM and won't stop ever. I thought that if there are no more living contexts then my app will terminate automatically.

Comment: what about the image views , bitmaps.. are you releasing them

Comment: Well, I have a singleton for storing some application specific stuff. One of them is a list of Bitmaps. Do I have to do anything with them after closing the app contexts?

Comment: since u r stoppng ur map, ill suggest u to recycle the bitmaps , free the memory allocated to bitmaps,Imageviews etc

Comment: Slightly better. Now uses less memory (only 1 MB), but still running.

Comment: Use Exit() when terminating , it will kill ur app but releasing memory may take some time, if its 1mb and all it hardly matters

Comment: because the Views are their in the memory, it will get automatically cleared in some time

Comment: Okay, but If the user tries to close the service and after that it gets launched a few seconds later again then it crashes, because it tries to use recycled bitmaps and of course a lot of things remain the same as they were in the previous launch, because the app hasn't been terminated by the system yet.

Comment: arent u stopping the service ? or does your require the service to run in background

Comment: There is a close button in the service view and when the user touches the button it initiates a destroy intent which calls the stopSelf() method of the service and removes its notification. I unregister every broadcast receiver and release the resources allocated in the creation of the service. Are there any way to check which objects forces the app to be opened?

Comment: Sorry im not sure on that

Answer (score 0):

Android apps and their components have unique life cycles. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how android works, every activity and service you have, executes inside only one thread called UI thread which itself and other threads you create run in a single process.

Android doesn't close this process till systme has enough memory for new stuff so if you user wants to run your program again it launch's as fast as possible. But you can terminate the whole process using **exit()** function.

Actually the activity or service is not the program but piece of code which runs inside the UI thread inside program process, now the process is your program which can be started even with a broadcast receiver call!

Answer (score 0):

Calling finish() when you want to shut down the app completely should kill the app and free it's resources.